# Two Django apps with the same name

Tags: django

I want to use the apps from this library https://github.com/andreynovikov/django-rated-reviews in my **Django** project.

To do so, I need to add 'reviews' to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'reviews',
    ...
)
```

The problem is that I already have a (custom) app called 'reviews'.

What can I do?
Do I have to change my app name?

Comment: Yes, better you rename it. If not, I think you will have many problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even if django allows you to have two apps with same name, you **should** to change your app name if you want your application to be scalable and without errors because the interpreter may get confused at any time which can cause your application to crash. More:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12287

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21562